# Kubernetes Dashboard Ingress returning empty response from server

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress, amazon-eks

I  am trying to set up the kubernetes dashboard.  I have enabled the custom ssl certs from my domain and can curl the pod directly with no issues - i can curl the service and it works with no issues.  However, when I try to access via ingress I get (52) empty response from server.  I have an NLB forwarding to the port of nginx controller service (ingress works fine with another app).  Here is my ingress config:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
  labels:
    app: dashboard
    name: dashboard-ingress
  name: dashboard-ingress
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
spec:
  rules:
  - host: k8sdash.domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: kubernetes-dashboard
          servicePort: 443
        path: /
```

Here is the Daemonset config for my ingress controllers.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  annotations:
    deprecated.daemonset.template.generation: "3"
  creationTimestamp: "2020-05-19T15:48:13Z"
  generation: 3
  labels:
    app: lb
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    chart: nginx-ingress-1.36.3
    heritage: Tiller
    release: lb
  name: lb-controller
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "747622"
  selfLink: /apis/apps/v1/namespaces/kube-system/daemonsets/lb-controller
  uid: 19d830ba-f2d9-4c6f-bc8d-d64667a900c7
spec:
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: lb
      release: lb
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: lb
        app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
        component: controller
        release: lb
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - /nginx-ingress-controller
        - --default-backend-service=kube-system/lb-default-backend
        - --publish-service=kube-system/lb-controller
        - --election-id=ingress-controller-leader
        - --ingress-class=nginx
        - --configmap=kube-system/lb-controller
        env:
        - name: POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        image: quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.30.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 10254
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        name: lb-controller
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          hostPort: 80
          name: http
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 443
          hostPort: 443
          name: https
          protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 10254
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        resources: {}
        securityContext:
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
          capabilities:
            add:
            - NET_BIND_SERVICE
            drop:
            - ALL
          runAsUser: 101
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      hostNetwork: true
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      serviceAccount: lb
      serviceAccountName: lb
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
  updateStrategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 1
    type: RollingUpdate
status:
  currentNumberScheduled: 3
  desiredNumberScheduled: 3
  numberAvailable: 3
  numberMisscheduled: 0
  numberReady: 3
  observedGeneration: 3
```

Comment: had to enable ssl-passthrough on Controller via extraArgs then added it to annotations for ingress.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer do others can use it in the future in case they face similar issues.

Comment: knock knock facing this issue right now, could you post the answer.